# Error code 811 thrown on Adding a new owner

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have deployed my own instance of gnosis-safe. On the front-end when trying to add a new owner, right before submit button appears, "Estimating" button keeps on loading.

Alongside, on the console the following error is thrown -

```
index.js:1 Error: Code 811: Error calculating ERC721 transfer data for adding a Safe owner (You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Can you please provide any hints on where we should define the ABI? Is it being read from another package, where we have to define the appropriate chain ID reference?
Do we have to define it in the safe-transaction-service? -- p.s: Sorry for posting it as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation for making a comment or an upvote.